# Windows Azure Roles instances are taking longer than expected to start up

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

When starting my project in both debugging mode and without debugging I get an message informing me that roles instances are taking longer than expected to start up.

I've seen a number of threads posting that its a code issue in the roles but the code works fine on my colleagues machines.

Here is the diagnostic information from the emulator UI:

```
[Diagnostics] Information: Diagnostic process exited with code: 0
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\ashleyrobinson\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\731ee61a-70ac-4811-8c9b-279ef76ae10a\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\DUOSAzure\src\Projects\CloudUniformOrderingSystem\csx\Debug\roles\CloudService\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\ashleyrobinson\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\731ee61a-70ac-4811-8c9b-279ef76ae10a\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile "C:\Users\ashleyrobinson\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\731ee61a-70ac-4811-8c9b-279ef76ae10a\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\ashleyrobinson\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\731ee61a-70ac-4811-8c9b-279ef76ae10a\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown 66692520bb0a4ef8b40be2a6b222be3f -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-66692520bb0a4ef8b40be2a6b222be3f -parent 9640 -events
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-66692520bb0a4ef8b40be2a6b222be3f is signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-66692520bb0a4ef8b40be2a6b222be3f after the agent is initialized.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 9640 exits.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-02-08T10:21:45.552Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     12384
[MonAgentHost] Error:     12524
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ec0e0567-0246-43a7-b302-95ab15b
[MonAgentHost] Error:     netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f87
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_INTERNET_UNABLE_TO_DOWNLOAD_SCRIPT (12167)
[Diagnostics]: Checking for configuration updates 08/02/2013 10:22:16.
```

I'm using the 1.8 SDK.

Can anyone decipher what is causing the problem.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Restart Visual Studio and Compute emulator. If problem persist try reinstalling Windows Azure Tools.

Comment: @astaykov I've done this several times and this doesn't resolve the issue. I definitely have the most up to date tools and packages.

Comment: After a machine restart (before starting VS or Azure Emulator), could you check your Environment Variables for strange variables (such as RD_ROLEROOT, or generally anything that starts with RD). Also, if it is a webrole, configure your default browser to IE. Also close all IE/(or default browser) instances before running the project - just for check.

Comment: What is the role doing (functionally)?  Does it have multiple sites configured to use host headers?  I've seen the emulator be really slow and eventually fail if I have multiple sites configured with host headers, instead of ports (in the .csdef).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was causing the problem but it turned out to be the machine. It was a huge hassle but after a few days I set myself up on a new machine and everything worked fine. Something was clearly preventing my roles from launching but I'm guessing I was missing a vital piece of software somewhere.